# Is there a way to force the Invoke-DscResource cmdlet?

Tags: azure, powershell, powershell-2.0, dsc, pester

I am trying to use the Invoke-DscResource cmdlet in a series of tests (using Pester) to see if a configuration has been successfully applied to a VM.

This works 9/10 times, but sometimes the following error is thrown:

```
==> azure-arm.dsc_node: Cannot invoke the Invoke-DscResource cmdlet. The Consistency Check or Pull cmdlet is in progress and must return
==> azure-arm.dsc_node: before Invoke-DscResource can be invoked. Use -Force option if that is available to cancel the current operation.
==> azure-arm.dsc_node:     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (root/Microsoft/...gurationManager:String) [], CimException
==> azure-arm.dsc_node:     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MI RESULT 1
==> azure-arm.dsc_node:     + PSComputerName        : localhost
```

Is there a way to force the Invoke-DscResource cmdlet?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Desired State Configuration cannot run at the same time as another process is changing the configuration of the machine.

I would guess that you are running Invoke-DscResource before the process that you are testing is complete.

Try putting a pause in your test.

Comment: I unregister the VM from the Azure automation account once the configuration is fully applied. Is there a way to pause the LCM so that I can run Invoke-DscResource in my tests?